# How can i get the address from a Look up Table?

Tags: c, function-pointers, lookup-tables

I have a `main.c` with a `struct` and a lookup table.

Now I would like to "send" the address of the `struct head` to an other C file and call it.
How can I get the address from a lookup table named `head` and use it in an other C file?

```
// all is in the same main.c
//int main is in my main.c
int main()
{
    init();
    searcher();
    return 0;
}


//Look up tables are in my main.c too

static ExTable head[] ={
    {"hugo" , c ,NULL},
    {"bernd" , d ,NULL},
    {"anna" , a ,NULL},
    {"\0"}
};
```

I am only adding the `exTable` here for example, because all other (a-z) only have other names and subtabs.

```
static ExTable a[] = {    
    {"Say" , c ,NULL},
    {"Show" , b ,NULL},

    {"\0"}
};

//my init ... 
//here i think i would set the adress from my head
void init()
{

}

// in my tester.h 
// is my struct and  a lot of funktiondeclarations
typedef struct Table
{
    char* name;
    struct Table* subtab;
    void (*pfn)(char*);
} ExTable;
```

In my `tester.c` I have a `void findname(ExTable* table, char* input)` and
this should find the name. This method is uninteressted for you :) But it needs a `static Extable* table` and a `char*`,

I would use the Method in a other method in `tester.c`

```
  //searcher is in my tester.c
    void searcher()
    {
        //....................
        // inputs is a char[]
        inputs[strlen(inputs)-1] = '\0';
        // in head should be the adress from the head Look Up Table
//head is only an exable , i dont have it in my program because i dont know who i became the adress from my header LUT in my main to my tester.c in my parameter. when i wrote header , it doesn't works
        findname(head, inputs);
    }
```

Comment: You've described your program, but there's no question in there. What problem are you having?

Comment: You apparently already know how to pass parameters to functions, as indicated by `findname`, so it's unclear how you're having a problem with adding parameters to `searcher`.

Comment: i would become the adress from my exTable Header to give it / used in mx findname(header, inputs); but i dont know how i became the adress from my main.c to my tester.c in the argument from findname.

Comment: head is inly an exable , i dont have it in my program because i dont know who i became the adress from my header LUT  in my main to my tester.c in my parameter. when i wrote header , it doesn't works